# Class/struct definition error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am porting/updating some really old code and my C++ is not very sharp (I'm mostly a C programmer).  I received this error - how do I fix it and can someone explain this mess?  Note line 512 is the struct definition - the first line?

```
In file included from src/aaa_dict_mngr.cxx:38:0:
./include/aaa_parser_avpvalue.h:512:41: error: expected template-name before '<' token
./include/aaa_parser_avpvalue.h:512:41: error: expected '{' before '<' token
./include/aaa_parser_avpvalue.h:512:41: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
```

Offending code:

```
struct DiamidentGrammar : public grammar<DiamidentGrammar>
{
  template <typename ScannerT>
  struct definition
  {
    definition(DiamidentGrammar const& self)  
    { 
      diameterIdentity = realm;
      realm = label >> *('.' >> label);  // No recursive rule allowed.
      label = diameterName | diameterDname;
      diameterName = alpha_p >> *(alnum_p | '-');
      diameterDname = digit_p >> +(alnum_p | '-');
    }
    rule<ScannerT> diameterIdentity, realm, label, diameterName, diameterDname;
    rule<ScannerT> const& start() const { return diameterIdentity; }
  };
};
```

Comment: It looks like you have not included the header where the `grammar<>` class template is defined.

Comment: Included #include <boost/spirit/utility/grammar_def.hpp>, but same eror

Comment: @KerrekSB Just a heads-up, I think you, with others, have made the wrong call here, closing this question for the reasons stated (TBC...)

Comment: /cc @juanchopanza I think my answer (see the Coliru link?) makes it plenty clear that the sample was (more than) enough information to go by (I'm afraid people have allowed themselves to be lead by the (bad) question title alone?).

Comment: Mmm. Apparently it was @MattMcNabb who added the boost tags. Okay then, thanks Matt, I would never have spotted the question without at least the [tag:boost] tag. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just ancient Spirit code. You need to use the classic headers/namespace:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2bfeea2e5844b01)**

Oh and by all means, upgrade! Spirit V2 is years old and SpiritX3 is around the corner

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp>

using namespace boost::spirit::classic;

struct DiamidentGrammar : public grammar<DiamidentGrammar>
{
    template <typename ScannerT>
        struct definition
        {
            definition(DiamidentGrammar const& self)  
            { 
                diameterIdentity = realm;
                realm = label >> *('.' >> label);  // No recursive rule allowed.
                label = diameterName | diameterDname;
                diameterName = alpha_p >> *(alnum_p | '-');
                diameterDname = digit_p >> +(alnum_p | '-');
            }
            rule<ScannerT> diameterIdentity, realm, label, diameterName, diameterDname;
            rule<ScannerT> const& start() const { return diameterIdentity; }
        };
};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Your absolutely correct!  Heh.. well this is a very very very old application - opendiameter ;)

Comment: FWIW: this is what it would look like in modern SpiritV2: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/994216f654653b87